# Entity Framework and WCF. Best approach?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1

I'm developing n-layer architecture, and for the data access layer I am using Entity Framework 4.1. 
The database oonly expose stored procedures. I also have an additional layer, service layer, developed in WCF. 
For each service call, use a new data context in a using statement. 
Considering that service calls will reach 1000 per second, this approach is right?

Best Regards.

Comment: _service calls will reach 1000 per second_ What does this mean ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but curious to know why you would use entity framework if everything is stored procedure. ORMs are supposed to eliminate the need for stored procedures. If you just have to call the sps, wouldn't using plain ado.net suffice?

Comment: If you already have Stored Procedures, then you have no need for the EF, and the added features in EF will detract from performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 per second - if your service really has to do something you will need either very good server or load balanced environment.

If your database exposes only stored procedures and you cannot execute direct SQL (= you cannot use LINQ) there is no reason to use EF. Actually there are many reason why you should not because it will not give you any additional value except much worse performance. Also if your stored procedures use for example multiple result sets, table value parameters and some other advanced techniques you will not be able to use them from EF 4.1 at all.

Using direct ADO.NET will allow you executing queries asynchronously which can lead to [asynchronous WCF service operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx#Y574) = better utilization of your computing power and better throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You should worry more about server load balancing , sclability , WCF performance issues including but not limited to concurrency , thorottling .  You should chose binding that can scale easily as per your need with minium breakdown time in future.

Additionally,You should make sure that you are doing a good multithreaded design on your backend to support your benchmark of 1000 calls/sec ( I am still wondering what it is though) and to increase throughput of your service.

EF doesnt play any part in your case . You need raw performance here . Dont kill by adding another layer of unnecessary stuff.

For load balancing you can start here [Loadbalancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273122.aspx)